# Designing and implementing SaaS Application with Muti-tenancy GraphDB (Neo4J / ArangoDB)

Tags: node.js, neo4j, multi-tenant, graph-databases, arangodb

I am developing a SaaS Application with the following Technology:

- NestJS (Node)
- DB (NEO4J, ArangoDB)
- Nginx for proxy (Micro-services Approach)

The SaaS Application will be hosting many distinct companies, as clients.
The data from 2 different companies must be fully isolated in the GraphDB.
2 different companies may have different data structures and models.

ENQUIRIES
Here are my enquiries:

- How to setup Multi-tenancy on a GraphDB (Neo4J / ArangoDB)?
- Is a totally separate required GraphDB instance required for each company?
- Is it possible to host 2 companies on the same GraphDB, yet maintain isolation?

Can anyone please suggest an optimal solution for this type of architecture?
Thanks for your time

Best regards

Comment: Neo4j 4+ is multi-tenant: https://neo4j.com/developer/multi-tenancy-worked-example/

Answer (score 2):

Since Neo4j 4.0 multi-tenancy is supported via multi-database.

In the system database you can create as many databases as you want and from a client select the database to talk to on a session by session basis, so you can use each database for a tenant.

Here is the JS API:

[https://neo4j.com/docs/api/javascript-driver/current/class/src/driver.js~Driver.html#instance-method-session](https://neo4j.com/docs/api/javascript-driver/current/class/src/driver.js%7EDriver.html#instance-method-session)

Each database instance can handle hundreds or thousands of databases.

[image]

With Neo4j Fabric enabled you can do cross-database federated queries.

here are some more examples

- https://adamcowley.co.uk/neo4j/multi-tenancy-neo4j-4.0/
- https://graphaware.com/neo4j/2020/02/06/multi-tenancy-neo4j.html
- https://neo4j.com/developer/multi-tenancy-worked-example/

Answer (score 0):

With ArangoDB you only need one instance and can simply use a database per tenant.

Each database is isolated, for example, AQL queries run in the context of a single database and you can only access the collections and named graphs of that database.

[image: ArangoDB Architecture - Hierarchy of Databases, Collections and Documents]

You can create an ArangoDB user for each customer and restrict its access to the respective database to achieve the desired isolation.

For scalability and resilience, there is also the [OneShard](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/architecture-deployment-modes-cluster-architecture.html#oneshard) feature (Enterprise Edition / [managed service](https://cloud.arangodb.com/)). It enables you to have a cluster where each database is treated like a single shard, i.e. all collections of a customer are stored on one DB-Server (excluding replicas), so that queries can be executed locally on that node. This is especially beneficial for graph traversals.